# Python, работа с процессами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хорошо, мне надо сделать так что бы python проверял видит ли он java.exe
Вот до чего я додумался:

```
procn = "java.exe"
while procn == "java.exe":
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
             if proc.name() == procn:
                     print("Server is run")
             if proc.name() != procn:
                     print("Server is not run")
```

Но он всегда говорит что java.exe не запущен, почему?

Хотя:

```
procn = "java.exe"
while procn == "java.exe":
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
             if proc.name() == procn:
                     print("Server is run")
```

Говорит что java.exe запущен....

**Проблема решена**

```
import psutil
dddd = ""
procn = "java.exe"
while True:
    is_run = any(proc.name() == procn
             for proc in psutil.process_iter())

    if is_run:
        dddd = "On"
    else:
        dddd = "Off"
    print(dddd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый код перебирает все процессы и ДЛЯ КАЖДОГО выводит либо "Server is run", либо "Server is not run".

То есть, скорее всего где-то среди этих сообщений есть и сообщение о том, что сервер запущен, но его сложно заметить среди остальных.

Вам нужно сначала пройтись по всем процессам, определить, есть ли среди них хотя бы один 'java.exe', а уже потом выводить сообщение о том, что сервер запущен.

Например так:

```
is_run = any(proc.name() == procn
             for proc in psutil.process_iter())

if is_run:
    print("Server is run")
else:
    print("Server is not run")
```

PS: И, кстати, цикл while у вас имеет какое-то бессмысленное условие. Он у вас будет просто бесконечно повторятся, и совершенно не понятно, зачем вы это условие проверяете.

Comment: Если нужен бесконечный цикл, то лучше просто написать while True - так другой программист, который будет читать ваш код, сразу поймёт, что вы имели в виду. А вставлять произвольное условие там, где оно не несёт никакого смысла - не очень хорошая практика ))

Comment: Эх, как не крути он постоянно говорит что Java не запущен

Comment: Надо отлаживать, дистанционно тут ничего сказать нельзя. Но если второй код из вашего вопроса у вас даёт положительный результат, а мой код - нет, то вы что-то делаете не так.

Comment: *Картинка виселицы"

Comment: Попробуйте с помощью print выводить состояние всех переменных и выражений, которые вычисляются в коде и смотреть - соответствуют ли они тому, что вы ожидаете в них видеть.

Comment: Сяба, решено, не знаю как но решено))